# pyqt installation question

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4, ubuntu

Im planing to do some GUI development using pyqt4 pykde and python3.1 on Kubuntu 10.4. In the research I did I found out that most of the things are available as packages in repositories and some of the packages are preinstalled. Only thing is I'm not able to figure out what to install and what not to. Can someone please give me a list of packages that I need to install to do GUI development using python3.1 pyQt4 and pyKDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qt-designer is inside the new qtcreator (former package was qt-creator).
install -doc packages as you like, also look for -examples, they are very helpful.

for your convenience:

aptitude install 
    python31
    python-qt4 
    python-qt4-doc
    pyqt4-dev-tools
    python-kde4
    qtcreator

For an IDE, look in question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784/poll-which-python-ide-editor-is-the-best)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `python-qt4 qt4-designer qt4-dev-tools`.